# jquery scrollable displays all items

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a basic list using jQuery scrollable, but I have a problem in that the entire list is being displayed - not a subset as supposedly defined by the 'size' parameter in scrollable().

I am testing in Chrome, and it does not detect any javascript errors. Futhermore, the list seems to be capturing the mousewheel when I hover over it, so something seems to be working.

I based this off this example [here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/vertical.html), and seeing as the example works in my browser, I must making some really damn obvious error. I am using the same css/js as was provided in the example.

Can anyone enlighten me?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scroll.css" type="text/css" media="print">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script> 
// execute your scripts when DOM is ready. this is a good habit 
$(function() {         

    // initialize scrollable  
    $("div.scrollable").scrollable({ 
        vertical:true,  
        size:10,
        clickable:false

    // use mousewheel plugin 
    }).mousewheel();     

    // get handle to scrollable API 
    var api = $("div.scrollable").scrollable(); 

    // append new item using jQuery's append() method 
    for (i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
        api.getItemWrap().append( 
        '<p>added'+i+'</p>'
        );  
    }

    api.reload().end();      
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>


        <div class="scrollable vertical">     

            <!-- root element for the items --> 
            <div class="items"> 

            </div> 

        </div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't look like it's including the jquery tools js. Is that the problem?

It would be helpful to have a live link of your page, or for you to include the style here.

Also, when linking to jquery, it makes it easier for me to copy/paste and debug if you use:

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe the document ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```